# Error (10381) de VHDL

Tags: vhdl

estoy haciendo un trabajo y no para de salirme `Error (10381): VHDL Type Mismatch error at Trabajo_3.vhd(20): indexed name returns a value whose type does not match "std_logic_vector", the type of the target expression`
El tranajo es ". Un sistema tiene tres entradas de datos X2, X1 y X0 y dos señales de control C1, C0 binarias
(valores 0 o 1) y una única salida Z. En función de las entradas de datos se realizan los
siguientes cálculos aritméticos (VER HOJA POR GRUPO 2º a). En base a los resultados
aritméticos se quiere saber si se cumple una de la siguientes cuatro condiciones, seleccionando la condición mediante los valores de las entradas de control C1 y C0, lo que activará (si se cumple) o no (si no se cumple) la salida Z del sistema.
Realizar una descripción VHDL del problema lógico, usando una arquitectura generada
directamente de la especificación (usando sentencias del tipo IF-ELSE, CASE, LOOP,
operadores aritméticos, incluyendo ABS: valor absoluto, y MOD o REM: resto de una división,
operaciones relacionales, etc, pero sin generar directamente la tabla de verdad del problema).

```
   library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
--use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity Trabajo_3 is 
port (X: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 1);
    C0,C1: in std_logic;
    Z: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 1));
end Trabajo_3;

architecture uno of Trabajo_3 is 
begin
process(X,C0,C1)
type vectores is array (3 downto 0) of integer range -10 to 10;
variable F: vectores;
variable promedio, Vmin, mayor: std_logic;
begin
for i in 0 to 3 loop
    F(i):=(conv_integer(X(i)));
end loop;
F(0):=((-2)*X(4))+((-3)*X(3))+(4*X(2))+3;
F(1):=4*X(4)-5*X(3)+X(2)+1;
F(2):=-3*X(4)+X(3)+X(2)+2;
F(3):=-4*X(4)+3*X(3)-X(2)+3;
promedio:=(F0 AND F1 AND F2 AND F3) MOD 4;
Vmin:=10;
if((F(0) /= F(1))AND(F(0)/= F(2))AND(F(0)/= F(3))AND(F(1)/= F(2))AND(F(1) /= F(3))AND(F(2)/=F(3)))
then Z(4)<='1';
else Z(4)<='0';
end if;
for i in 0 to 3 loop
    if (F(i) > 1) then 
        mayor:= mayor AND '1';
    end if;
    if (F(i) >= Vmin) then 
        Vmin:=F(i);
    end if;
end loop;
if (mayor >= 3) then
    Z(2)<='1';
else Z(2)<='0';
end if;
if (Vmin >= 1) then
    Z(1)<='1';
    else Z(1)<='0';
end if;
if (promedio >= 2) then
    Z(3)<='1';
    else Z(3)<='0';
end if;

end process;
end uno;
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es en la línea 20 que, si conté correctamente, es:

```
    F(i):=(conv_integer(X(i)));
```

Y el problema es que la función *conv_integer()* no admite como argumento a un *std_logic* (que es lo que obtienes al indexar un *std_logic_vector*), sino que [uno de estos 4 tipos](https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/%7Eggbaker/reference/std_logic/arith/conv_integer.html).

Puedes hacer una doble conversión, pero no sé si es lo más conveniente. Si quieres compartir toda la consigna un poco más ordenada te ayudo con gusto :D.

Para más información sobre qué conversiones son incluidas en *numeric_std* (paquete oficial del IEEE y por lo tanto el recomendado para esto), puedes [ver aquí](https://nandland.com/common-vhdl-conversions/).